# Find HTML-tag by text in BS4

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Let assume we have HTML-pattern like

`<p class='cls1'> Hello </p>`

So I want to find tag `<p>` (and I don't know what tag is around the text for now) by searching *"Hello"* using BS4.

It should be smth like

```
full_string = soup.find(text=re.compile('Hello'))
full_string.get_parent_tag() # <p>
full_string.get_parent_class() # cls1
```

Is it possible in BS4?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible.

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


your_html = """<p class='cls1'> Hello </p>"""
print(BeautifulSoup(your_html, "html.parser").find_all(lambda t: t.name == "p" and re.compile("Hello")))
```

Output:

```
[<p class="cls1"> Hello </p>]
```

If you don't know a tag you're after, you could try this:

```
from lxml import html


your_html = """<p class='cls1'> Hello </p>"""
print(html.fromstring(your_html).xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Hello')]"))
```

Output:

```
[<Element p at 0x7f2b172ae5e0>]
```

Comment: Thanks for response! But the question is what if I don't know tag and wanna search only by text 'Hello'

Comment: Well... you should at least have a tag you're aiming for but if there's no such you could try `xpath` and `lxml`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see your update! It's exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

To search a tag by text, you can use a CSS Selector `p:contains(<text>)`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<p class='cls1'> Hello </p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one('p:contains("Hello")').text)
```

Output:

```
Hello
```